# Why does a trait bound of an associated type cause an evaluation overflow when the bound is guaranteed to always hold?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I have a generic extensible AST:

```rust
pub trait Schema: Clone {
    type Expr: Clone;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Expr<S: Schema> {
    IntLiteral,
    Add(Box<S::Expr>, Box<S::Expr>),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ParserSchema;
impl Schema for ParserSchema {
    type Expr = Expr<ParserSchema>;
}

pub fn main() {
    type ParserExpr = <ParserSchema as Schema>::Expr;
    let expr: ParserExpr = ParserExpr::IntLiteral;
    let e = expr.clone();
}
```

When I compile this piece of code ([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e1daa7cd2b69cf6a66419da5b437bf9)), I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `Expr<ParserSchema>: Clone`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     type Expr = Expr<ParserSchema>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: required by a bound in `Schema::Expr`
  --> src/main.rs:2:16
   |
2  |     type Expr: Clone;
   |                ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Schema::Expr`
```

If I manually implement the `Clone` trait for `Expr` ([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=593614041e5c5195cac73cd48fe4deda)), it compiles without a hitch:

```rust
impl<S: Schema> Clone for Expr<S> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            Expr::IntLiteral => Expr::IntLiteral,
            Expr::Add(ref lhs, ref rhs) => Expr::Add(lhs.clone(), rhs.clone()),
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically, `#[derive(Clone)]` and the manual implementation of `Clone` should behave identically. However, if I look at the generated code for `#[derive(Clone)]`, I see the following (cleaned up for readability):

```rust
impl<S: Clone + Schema> Clone for Expr<S>
where
    S::Expr: Clone,
{
    fn clone(&self) -> Expr<S> {
        todo!("omitted")
    }
}
```

The `where S::Expr: Clone` bound seems to be the culprit; if I remove it, the example compiles successfully. However, I do not understand why this `where` clause would cause an evaluation overflow. If `S: Schema`, then `S::Expr: Clone` is guaranteed to hold. What makes `rustc` error with an evaluation overflow when adding a clause that is guaranteed to always hold?

Comment: @Shepmaster The question I am asking is: I understand the `where S::Expr: Clone` bound causes rustc to bail out with an evaluation overflow, but _why is that the case_, given that this bound is guaranteed to always hold?

Comment: But it *doesn't* always hold, it's an infinitely self-referencing requirement: `Expr<ParserSchema>` (from `<Schema as ParserSchema>::Expr`) only implements `Clone` if `Expr<ParserSchema>` implements `Clone` which only implements `Clone` if `Expr<ParserSchema>` (from `<Schema as ParserSchema>::Expr`) implements `Clone` .... .

Comment: @Shepmaster doesn't the compiling version also have that problem? `Expr<ParserSchema>` only implements `Clone` if `ParserSchema` implements `Schema`, which can only do so if its associated type `Expr` (a.k.a. `Expr<ParserSchema>`) implements `Clone` ... why does that compile but the former doesn't?

Comment: @kmdreko that's the core question, I suppose. I assume it's a limitation of the trait system, as when it's computing `impl<S: Schema> Clone for Expr<S>` no loop is needed as it can terminate and say "so long as `S` implements `Schema`". Proving that can be a separate check later, not part of a cycle.